# Visual Studio 2010 Dont debug in breakPoints

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, breakpoints

I'm working on a project and suddenly the debug ignore my breakpoints and doesn't debug,

Comment: check if your breakpoint was disabled by accident and try to restart VS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the dropdown near on the debug toolbar shows "Debug" and not "Release".

Comment: Breakpoints still work in Release mode. Visual Studio still attaches the debugger to your process.

Comment: its only in one specific Page now, it is in Debug mode

Comment: @Danny: I don't understand why you've accepted this as the answer. As I mentioned, breakpoints will still work in "Release" mode, and you said yourself that the project was already in "Debug" mode anyway. How did this fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to "hit" the break point in "RELEASE" mode go to:

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General and UN-CHECK "Just my code" option, in order to enable loading symbols and actualy hitting a break point ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Visual Studio just gets all confused.  I've found restarting Visual Studio, unsetting/resetting breakpoints, and commenting out the places where it's falling over all help to trip Visual Studio into working again.